# BZR: Is it possible to completely delete old revisions?

Tags: bazaar

Is it possible to remove some old revisions in order to compact database?
I don't mean to revert anything or remove sth from the middle. I would like to just delete from database everything older than specified date.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Deleting old revisions" is not possible.

If you want to compact storage, I can think of 2 options.

1. Run `bzr reconcile`. The main function of this command is to fix inconsistencies detected by `bzr check`, but as its help says, it may do some additional optimizations too:

   > At the same time it is run it may recompress data resulting in
   >   a potential saving in disk space or performance gain.

   You may want to take a backup of the repo before you do this!
2. Replace your repository and branches with a clean new replica. You can create replicas of a Bazaar branch using the `bzr branch` or `bzr push` commands with a target location outside of your current shared repository (if you are using one), and the new replica branches will be automatically optimized and compact.

Example: replicate the standalone branch `/srv/mybranch` into `/newsrv/mybranch`:

```
bzr branch /srv/mybranch /newsrv/mybranch
```

Example: replicate the shared repository `/srv/repo` into `/newsrv/newrepo`:

```
bzr init-repo /newsrv/newrepo --no-trees
cd /srv/repo
bzr branches -R | while read branch; do bzr push -d "$branch" /newsrv/newrepo/"$branch" --create; done
```